# Extra small RF PCB antenna - GND plane

Tags: antenna, ground, pcb-antenna, ground-plane

My new PCB design is about 25 mm * 25 mm, this is not enough for a proper 868 MHz antenna ground plane, I am using the [0868AT43A0020](https://www.johansontechnology.com/datasheets/antennas/0868AT43A0020.pdf) chip antenna where at least a 20 mm * 40 mm GND plane is required. The first prototypes confirm the weak RF performances. what is the standard practice when it comes to dipole antenna when the ground plane of the PCB is extremely small and not sufficient?

A picture of the PCB with the battery behind:
[image]

Comment: why are you asking about dipoles when you deal with a chip antenna? A proper dipole will be much, much larger.

Comment: The standard practice is to live with the shortfall or make the GP more suitable. BTW a half wave dipole antenna does not need a GP. A quarter wave monopole antenna does.

Comment: What range to do you get and what range do you want?

Comment: are you sure that that ground plane is needed?

Comment: With those small dimensions its possible for you to tune the antenna to your frequency of interest. However, it will be really narrow band, and detune easily.

Comment: I already tuned the antenna, the radio chip outputs 13 dBm however it only radiate around -14 dBm. There is also a coin cell battery placed under the PCB which reduces the performances further. Other PCBs with bigger ground plane can radiate 5 dBm

Comment: A photo of your board, with the same stuff around it as when you tested the radiation, would be helpful.

Comment: Seems to me like that "big" battery would act like a ground plane beneath the antenna.

Comment: The first prototypes confirm the weak RF performances: is this both tx and rx. Do you have conducted measurements for reference and comparison.

Comment: @Mikey, The PCB works in TX mode only, for the measurments: the radio chip outputs 13 dBm however the PCB only radiate around -14 dBm

Comment: @TarikMokafih How are you measuring Total Radiated Power? Could you try and move the battery to the right - away from the antenna. Its now directly under the antenna and it is affecting it for sure.

Comment: @Mikey, I already removed the battery, re-tuned the antenna the radiated power increased to -8 dBm, but still not enough (measured in Anechoic chamber at 3m from antenna and with standard EMC lab amplification)

Comment: @TarikMokafih Are you measuring a 3D sphere to get the TRP. Or are you measuring ERP, or EIRP. Are you sure that you are actually measuring in the direction of max antenna gain?

Comment: @Mikey I don't know if the reception antenna is isotropic or not, but the antenna and PCB are rotated around all axes and only the max value kept

Comment: I can guarantee it is not isotropic :) Now, if you are only rotating in two axes, you might not be capturing the maximum direction of radiated power. In addition, the margin of error in a 3m room can be +/- several decibels. I think what might be contributing to your unexpectectly low power is that your are not measuring the direction of max power and that theres a few dB's of error in the setup.

Comment: In addition, can you please add S11 measurement of the antenna.

Comment: @Mikey Thanks for your help, I considered already all these points and spent enough time on the problem to know for sure that beside the battery nearby the problem is, the design of ground plane and its size/antenna combination

Comment: If your S11 is, say below -10 dB, and the antenna is not super narrow band (power not burning to heat too much), the power should be radiating better than what you are measuring.

Comment: Typically these little chip antennas require a large ground plane to radiate with reasonable efficiency (usually at least a quarter-wavelength long). The ground plane is, effectively, part of the antenna.

Answer (score 1):

the only place in the document you link to that contains 20×40mm² dimensions is the eval board. That's just "randomly" in that size.

What's important is that the chip is offset some 1mm from the **edge** of a ground plane, and that you have the folded whip as specified, and that you properly **match** your antenna, as specified in multiple places of the data sheet. My guess is you forgot the latter.

Comment: are these the matching instructions? https://www.johansontechnology.com/tuning.html

Comment: all design instructions are followed and the antenna was matched. However I still get poor RF performance compared to bigger PCBs

Comment: @Tarik, you'll probably need to share your schematic and layout to get a useful answer then. Also are you enclosing the pcb in a housing of some kind?